# Why is the Lambda Expression not valid in this Include()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I'm working with EFCore for the first time, after moving from EF6, and for some reason I keep getting this error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Lambda expression used inside Include is not valid.'

Here is my Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        using (var IJ = IJContext.CreateNew(false))
        {
            var ChargeList = iJ.Charges.Where(charge => charge.CourtCase.CaseNumber == "13457894561")
                                             .Include(charge => charge.ChargeDate)
                                             .ToList();
            return View(ChargeList);
        }
    }
}
```

Am I missing something important here? Does EFCore handle Lambdas totally differently or something?

Comment: What is the exact error type and message?

Comment: Can you add the `Charge` class to the question?

Comment: is `ChargeDate` a complex type or just a `DateTime` ? if it is a datetime why do you whant to include it ?

Comment: `Include` is meant for navigation properties to indicate that you want EF to pull the related data from those tables.  If `ChargeDate` is just a regular property (and thus just a column in a table) then you don't need to use `Include`.

Comment: Isn't `.Inlcude()` for pulling in additional complex types/tables? `ChargeDate` wouldn't, from a first glance, appear to be a complex type. Edit: I think we all just said the same thing.

Comment: @Taborator `Include` is for passing the navigation property name that you want to eager load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the `ChargeDate` is not a related entity. Check [Retaled entities documentation to see the purpose of include](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/querying/related-data)

Seems like you either have not a relationship between the types and that you want to use something like the select property to get new objects based on the data already retrieved from the query.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the signature of the `Include` extension method it looks like as follows:

```
public static IIncludableQueryable<TEntity, TProperty> Include<TEntity, TProperty>( 
      this IQueryable<TEntity> source,
      Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> navigationPropertyPath)
      where TEntity : class
{
       // Method body
}
```

The paramter `navigationPropertyPath` expecting a lambda expression representing the navigation property to eager load the data for that navigation property. But you are passing the entity property `ChangeDate` which is not navigation property.

For more details: [EF Core Eager loading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data#eager-loading)